# Is there any way to get alert and prompt buttons to follow the UI Style guide for add-ons

Tags: google-apps-script

I really don't want to create a full html dialogue box for a simple yes no question, when it is built into getUI() api.   My problem is that prompt and alert function don't seem to conform to the UI Style guide for add-ons.  This is causing an issue when trying to get it published, because I can't make them blue, or work when enter is clicked on the keyboard.

So is there any way to properly style alert and prompt boxes, or does anyone have any tricks that they are using.

The one thing I did was change my non-button alerts from alert to using toast instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI style guide specifically says '[And don't use UI service to create a public add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style)', so no. You must use the HTML service.

Comment: @HDCerberus- UiApp Service and UI.alert and prompts are completely different things... the doc you refer to is not about prompts and alerts. That said, I agree that your conclusion is right: HTML is actually the way to go.

Comment: @Sergeinsas Hmm. Interesting point. I read this more as 'Don't use anything but the CSS service' (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/css), rather then 'Specifically don't use the UI service' (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service) and would consider UI alert part of 'UI service', but I can see what you mean. Thanks for the clarification! =)